# Concatenating variables which hold integers

Tags: javascript, string, variables

Which is the best way to concatinate 2 variables that hold integers ?

```
var var1 = 1;
var var2 = 2;

console.log(var1 + var2) //result 3; expected 1 2
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use string concatenation explicitly by including a string literal:

```
console.log(var1 + " " + var2);
```

Or in a different situation where you didn't want the space, you could use:

```
console.log(var1 + "" + var2);
```

or perform the string conversions first explicitly, and then concatenate them:

```
console.log(var1.toString() + var2.toString());
```

Or use [`concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/concat):

```
console.log(String.prototype.concat(var1, var2));
```

Comment: Sorry, for some reason I was thinking this was a C# question... ignore me.

Comment: With `String.prototype.concat()` you don't need to convert to a string previously.

Comment: @Wyatt: Great! Glad we got there in the end :) Edited into the answer.